# Unexpected long long value in C++

Tags: c++, loops, output, long-long

In my code I simply scan values of t, n and m respectively. While debugging I found that whatever value I give to m, it is taking the value 0. You can run this code for input :

```
1
3 4
```

Here, the output should be 4, but unexpectedly its 0. 
On the other hand, when I scan the values of n and m after the for loop, the output comes as expected (i.e. 4 in this case). I have commented out that line so that you people can figure out why this is happenning.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long t,n,m,i,j;
    scanf("%lld",&t);           // Scan t (of no use)
    while(t--){

        scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&m);       // If I scan n and m here, the 
                                       //output is always 0
        long long x[9000],y[9000],ans[9000],in=0;
        for(i=1;i<=9000;i++){
        ans[i]=0;
        x[i]=0;
        y[i]=0;
        }
    //scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&m);//Output is correct if I scan the values here
        cout<< m << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: why not use cin for reading?

Comment: why using the C tag? edited out

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=9000;i++)` ==> `for(i=0;i<9000;i++)`

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=9000;i++)` you're off by one, here. It should be `for(size_t i=0;i<9000;++i)` as C and C++ use zero-based arrays.

Comment: @BobBills That's for faster I/O. You may even use printf for output as I've already included <bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: BTW, see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1362568)

Comment: @mch It doesn't matter if I'm not giving any value to the index at zeroth position, I don't have to use that array at all.

Comment: @UtkarshPandey Writing past the end of the array (as you are doing currently) invokes undefined behavior. You can't predict the output of the program, which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Your answer is accepted :)
I am getting the desired output now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i = 9000`, you will end up accessing an out-of-bounds memory in the following statements. This leads to [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) behaviour.

```
ans[i]=0;
x[i]=0;
y[i]=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Classic "[off by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)" error. 
change your for loop to:

```
for(i=0;i<9000;++i){
    ans[i]=0;
    x[i]=0;
    y[i]=0;
}
```